# "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dep..."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io, warnings

my React Website is constantly reloading and I don't know why. I checked every `useEffect()` on a recursion, but didn't find any :(
The Rest of the Warning:

```
at Navigate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38653:5)
    at div
    at GameLobby (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:257:82)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38710:15)
```

So looks like it has to do something with the `<Navigate>`

```
const GameLobby = (props) =\> {
const \[userName, setUserName\] = useState('');
const \[foundPlayer, setFoundPlayer\] = useState(false);
const \[socket, setSocket\] = useState(null);
const \[roomId, setRoomId\] = useState('');
const \[opponent, setOpponent\] = useState('');
const \[startGame, setStartGame\] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setUserName(props.userName);
        setSocket(props.socket);
    },[]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!socket)  return;
            socket.emit('find_game', userName);
            socket.on('joinedGame', (opponent, roomId) => {
                console.log("Partie gefunden: " + roomId + " gegner: " + opponent);
                setRoomId(roomId);
                setOpponent(opponent);
                setFoundPlayer(true);
            })
    }, [socket]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(foundPlayer && roomId.length > 0 && opponent.length > 0 && userName.length > 0) {
            setStartGame(true);
            //I tested this here in my console, it's not the origin
        }
    }, [foundPlayer, roomId, opponent, userName]);
    
    
    return (
                <div>
                    { startGame ?
                            <Navigate to={'/game:' + roomId} />
                    :
                        <div>
                            <p>Waiting for opponent...</p>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/game:roomId' element={<ChessGame socket={socket} userName={userName} opponent={opponent} />}/>
                    </Routes>
                </div>
    )

}

export default GameLobby
```

I tried testing every `useEffect()` function with my console, to see if there is a recursion, but there isn't. Neither in my other files.